# Is there a downloadable distribution of Thrift for Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, thrift

I've been reading quite a bit about Thrift and it looks like a technology I'd really like to use. I'm having all sorts of trouble building the Windows distribution. I know a patch exists to build a Windows version, however I have not had much luck with this either.

Does anyone know of a pre-built distribution for Windows?

Or any suggestions on how to get the latest version of Thrift built (without turning my Windows machine into a pseudo *nix box).

Thanks
Rich

Comment: What compiler? I think I managed to build a version with MingW and Boost...

Comment: Sorry I should have expanded, Visual Studio 2005 (or higher)

Comment: Hm, I think they said they didn't support Windows specifically, so I suppose you're out of luck. There's a binary of the Thrift compiler for Windows, so you should still be able to compile some code, but for the actual library you might not be so lucky.

Comment: This seems to be the conclusion that I've reached. It's weird that they distribute the Windows compiler in built form, which is useless without the Thrift dll's to run the actual server and client. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You could still use the compiler to create all your Perl and Haskell and Erlang code, I suppose... and as I said, I think building with MingW (or at least Cygwin) is possible; perhaps it's worth your while figuring out what prevents porting to MSVC? I suppose the threading primitives would be the biggest stumbling point...

Comment: I would solely be using Thrift for communication in C++ between Windows apps and perhaps in the future c#. My main constraint is time, I don't really have the time to investigate the ins and outs of Thrift platform specific issues. I was hoping to download it, learn the API and be up and running.

Comment: @Rich Google shows this one: http://ripper234.com/p/thrift-win32-binary/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrift 0.8 now has VS projects for both the compiler and C++ library.  Get the snapshot release or the latest off of SVN
http://thrift.apache.org/download/

Edit: 0.8 has been officially released and the source is available as a tarball on the download page.

Edit2: The SVN trunk now has a cross-platform sample project under *thrift/contrib/transport-sample*

Comment: I've just got a copy of trunk, I haven't had time to build it, but it looks promising. Thanks for updating the question.

Comment: I'm hoping to carve out some time to contribute a sample VS client/server project so that Windows users can get up to speed more quickly. If you need help getting that going feel free to msg me (is that possible on Stack Overflow?).

Comment: After applying a patch I have made the 2010 version work. However be warned that Thrift _only_ works on 2010. If you try and build with 2005 you will get a host of problems, which is a real shame as our code base is currently 2005.

Comment: You're right the projects are VS2010. I'd think that it would be feasible to create equivalent VS 2005/2008 projects fairly easily. The Thrift community is always open to contributors :)
I'd take a stab at it but am focusing on getting out a new transport for Thrift.

Answer (score 0):

I ported the client part of Thrift to Windows C++ for my own open-source project. It should be easily usable in other Win32 or WinCE projects.

http://peoplesnote.codeplex.com - src\Evernote API\Thrift

Comment: Hi Don, I think I caught your link on a similar post to mine already on stack overflow. Great work porting the code, however I'd really like a port in the main branch of Thrift, as I imagine your port is several versions behind? Cheers Rich.

Comment: You are right. It is several versions behind. I should really get it complete and up to date, then submit to Apache Foundation. It would do a large amoung of good for not too much work.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, just download the exe from here:

http://thrift.apache.org/download/

exe listed for download there is standalone executable, no installation is needed.

I have used it to generate Smalltalk code, did not test other languages.

Comment: This is the compiler only, thanks for the reply, however I am after a Windows distribution of the run-time libraries (compiled in Visual Studio)